# I made my first typeclass and I got "Could not deduce (g ~ Int) from the context (Group g)"

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and I've tried to make my own typeclass here:

```
class Group g where
    makeGroup :: g -> g -> [g]

instance Group Int where
    makeGroup size offset = [ x `mod` size | x <- [1 + offset, size + offset]]

myTest :: (Group g) => Int -> Int -> [g]
myTest x y = makeGroup x y
```

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

**New problem**

The type signature `myTest :: (Group g) => g -> g -> [g]` compiles but throws this error

> `<interactive>:30:1:`
>       No instance for (Group g0) arising from a use of ‘it’
>       The type variable ‘g0’ is ambiguous
>       Note: there is a potential instance available:
>         instance Group Int -- Defined at ex.hs:4:10
>       In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
>       In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

What does this stem from?

Comment: To print something, it must be an instance of the `Show` typeclass.

Comment: @JeffAmes so I should make group part of the show type class? And if so how would I do that?

Comment: I think you'd want `class (Show g) => Group g where` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your class definition:

```
class Group g where
    makeGroup :: g -> g -> [g]
```

This means that in any use of `makeGroup`, all three occurrences of the type variable `g` must be instantiated to the same type.  But in your `myTest` function's type signature, you're indirectly saying that the first two occurrences are `Int`s but the third one could be any type `g` (caller's choice!) that satisfies the `Group` constraint:

```
myTest :: (Group g) => Int -> Int -> [g]
myTest x y = makeGroup x y
```

**EDIT:** Well, to make this much clearer, I should add that when we say that `g` could be "any type," more precisely this means that it could be **any type that `myTest`'s caller chooses**.  This is the way generic types work: the function `myTest` is like a **template** that the caller can **specialize** by choosing what type they would like `g` to be.

The notation is odd, but  `(g ~ Int)` in the error is a **type equality constraint**: Haskell is telling you that, given the declarations that you've provided elsewhere, in `myTest`'s signature `g`'s type must be the same as `Int`, but you've asserted that it could be any type `g` as long as that type implements `Group`.  That assertion is not compatible with what you've said elsewhere in the code.

Comment: So is the proper type signature just `myTest :: Int -> Int -> [Int]`?

Comment: @JomelI.: That would be one possible solution, yes.  But note that the function `myTest` would then just be the same as `makeGroup` but restricted with `g ~ Int`.

Comment: I thought that `instance` would convert `g` to `Int` or something along those lines. How should I properly leverage `instance`?

Comment: @AR7: Haskell doesn't modify or refine the types that you declare. It doesn't look at the `g` in `myTest`'s type signature and rewrite it to `Int` based on the inference that it must be the same as `Int`. It just interprets it as "any type can go here, as long as it's a `Group` instance." As Jomel I. suggests, if you declared `myTest :: Int -> Int -> [Int] ` the problem should go away; your actual `instance` declaration looks right (though I haven't actually checked it in the compiler, I could have missed something).

Comment: You could also declare the type of `myTest` as `(Group g) => g -> g -> [g]`.

Comment: @AR7: One more tip I would give is this: Haskell is a very, very literal language.  Most languages have a bit of "do what I mean" built into them, but Haskell has way less than that.  If you say `myTest :: (Group g) => Int -> Int -> [g]`, Haskell takes that absolutely literally as "the function `myTest` takes two `Int` arguments, and returns a result of whatever type `g` that the caller expects, as long as `g` is a `Group` instance." It doesn't question at all whether your type signature is what you meant—it just goes "Yes, boss, whatever you say!"

Comment: @LuisCasillas if you have the time I have a few more questions. You said `myTest :: Int -> Int -> [Int]` is one way to solve it. Is there a better way? The other question I have edited into the question and resulted from "`myTest` as `(Group g) => g -> g -> [g]`" as Jeff Ames suggested if you could please take a look.

Comment: @AR7: both `Int -> Int -> Int` and `Group g => g -> g -> [g]` are fine, the choice between them is entirely about what you want.